# Navigation between SwiftUI Views

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I don't know how to navigate between views with buttons.

The only thing I've found online is detail view, but I don't want a back button in the top left corner. I want two independent views connected via two buttons one on the first and one on the second.

In addition, if I were to delete the button on the second view, I should be stuck there, with the only option to going back to the first view being crashing the app.

In storyboard I would just create a button with the action `TouchUpInSide()` and point to the preferred view controller.

Also do you think getting into SwiftUI is worth it when you are used to storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to have a `@State`variable in the main view. This view will display one of the child views depending on the value of the `@State`variable:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showView1 = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showView1 {
                SomeView(showView: $showView1)
                    .background(Color.red)
            } else {
                SomeView(showView: $showView1)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you pass this variable to its child views where you can modify it:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @Binding var showView: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Switch View")
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to have more than two views you can make `@State var showView1` to be an `enum` instead of a `Bool`.